# Schotky diode in DC voltage setup

Tags: schottky

testing [1N5712](http://www.jnicm.com/UploadFile/2007113103613.pdf) with a resistor of \$10k\Omega\$ connected to 15VDC and the diode's cathode connected to ground and anode to the other side of resistor. I get about \$1.5ma\$ through the diode instead of \$200na\$ according to the spec. Why?

[image: schematic]

Comment: A schematic would be helpful, but it sure sounds like you have the diode backwards.

Comment: @MattYoung: If by "backwards", you mean forward-biased, rather than reverse-biased as the OP intended.

Comment: @DaveTweed That is exactly what I meant, but I can't tell if the OP would understand the difference.

Comment: circuitlab.com would do the job.

Comment: The question's language is unambiguous, if hard to understand, regarding the diode's direction. I've added a schematic.

Comment: I don't understand.  How is a little less than 1.5 mA not exactly what you should be expecting?

Answer (score 2):

**A datasheet search for 2n5712 indicates the device is an NPN transistor, not a diode.** Presumably the part number is mistyped, and the correct part number is [1N5712](http://www.jnicm.com/UploadFile/2007113103613.pdf), a small signal Schottky Diode.

By applying Ohms Law, `I = V / R` yields precisely 1.5 mA for 15 volts across 10 kΩ.

This indicates the diode is acting as a short circuit, not even as a forward biased diode. If the diode were forward biased, it would drop 0.41 volts, thus bringing the current in this mode to 1.46 mA.

This presents two possibilities:

- That the **diode is damaged**, with the contacts within it welded into a short circuit, due to some high current flow or manufacturing fault
- That the **current measurement was not precise**, the actual value is 1.46 mA, and the diode is connected forward biased instead of reverse.

---

Taking into account the subsequent edits to the question:

- Reverse leakage current at V<sub>R</sub> = 15 Volts is 100 nA, not 200 nA, as per the datasheet.
- To see this reverse leakage current in operation, the diode needs to be switched around, such that the *anode* is connected to ground, not the cathode.

Comment: Somebody was nice to draw the picture, but my diode is upside down compare to the diagram. Also I meant to write 1N5712 which is a diode.

Comment: @user18825 The question specifically mentions "*the diode's **cathode** connected to ground*", so the diagram matches that description. However, if you actually wired it the other way around (please correct the question), then as mentioned in my answer above, the diode is not working as a diode any more, it is a short-circuit.